# How can I write a python code for this question?

Tags: python-3.x

A snail falls at the bottom of a 125 cm well. Each day the snail rises 30 cm. But at night, while sleeping, slides 20 cm because the walls are wet. How many days does it take to escape from the well?

Comment: Please take a look at the [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) thread. This may not be a homework, but it would important to see what you have tried so far to solve this problem (or that you made an effort at least).

Comment: So far it sounds like a loop with index being the number of days, x being the height of the well.  Do While with index initialized to 0 and x to 125. condition would be if x is less than or equal to 0. in the loop body you will execute the distance traveled against x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
well = 125
cmPerDay = 30
cmPerNight = -20
snailHasNotEscaped = True
days = 0
totalCMs = 0

cmPerWholeDay = cmPerDay + cmPerNight

while snailHasNotEscaped:
   totalCMs += cmPerWholeDay
   days += 1
   print(days)
   if totalCMs >= well:
      snailHasNotEscaped = False

print("Congratulations! the snail escaped in", days, "days")
```

Comment: Thank you @SonicBoom2o, this worked!